# how I can make global suffix title in html page using php

Tags: php, html

I should make global suffix title for my website pages.
For example:

```
<title> Watches - "global suffix" </title>
```

Comment: perhaps by declaring a variable for that particular suffix in a file that is always included in your PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

header.php

```
<?php
    ....
    $title = 'Title';
    ....
```

index.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
....
<title> Watches - <?php echo $title; ?> </title>
```

Comment: Sorry, that I'm not clear, all my pages are html, not php, so when I include this code in html page, it doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot do this dynamically without some programming language. If it is HTML only, why is it tagged PHP???

Answer (score 0):

Thank you people. I found the answer. My php script doesn't in html file, because apache was not configured to use php for html extensions. I had add AddType application/x-httpd-php .html  in .htaccess file and now the code work. Thanks again!